# Services and Broadcast Receivers

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I just want to know if I have to declare a class that extends a service in my manifest?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name="com.cherise.readerwidget.MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.cherise.readerwidget.UpdateWidgetService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
</application>
```

In this class, I have an AsyncTask that does HttpConnections.

It doesnt seem to update my widget in the post execute.

Please help

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String details)
    {
        for(int widgetId : allWidgetIds)
        {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            //remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, news.get(0).getTitle());
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "Bloemfontein: " + details + " F");

            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
            clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
```

Comment: Is your BroadcastReceiver registered? Please post your manifest file.

Comment: check if onPostExecute is called at all ...

Comment: UpdateNews un = new UpdateNews();
un.execute();

Answer (score 1):

you should use this:

```
<service android:name=.UpdateWidgetService />
```

you have change with this also.

```
<service android:name= yourpackegename.UpdateWidgetService  android:enabled="true"/>
```

you can give full path of Package in which your service called...

Thanks!!

Comment: I did that, but its still not updating my widget. What can be the problem?

Comment: ..if the Service is inside the root package.

Comment: The service is in the root package and I included that line of service above application. Still not updating.

Comment: Did <service android:name= yourpackegename.UpdateWidgetService  android:enabled="true"/> this and it is still not working!!!!! :(

Comment: okk..just give me your packege name and also must sure with internet permission

Comment: Forgot about internet permission. Did include it. Still not working

Comment: so please post your Async task at where it executed??

Comment: Posted it! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to declare in the manifest file in the service tag.

Comment: <service android:name=".UpdateWidgetService: /> This should be under your <application> tag. Make sure your path to this service is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <service
        android:name="UpdateWidgetService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

Comment: Tried this, makes no difference!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I wrote startCommand instead of onStartCommand in my service class! :D So stupid! Thanks for everything